# Installing pyfm in virtual envornment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am not able to install the [`pyFM` module](https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM) in my virtualenv, only globally.

When I try to install it I get `ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils`. However, when I try to `pip install cython`, I get `unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory`.

I've even tried to `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc gcc-4.2` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work about doing ln -s /usr/bin/gcc gcc-4.2? What platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using IOS el capitan. 
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc gcc-4.2 does work itself, because when I do it again I get the msg that the file already exist. However I still get unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory. when I try to pip install something that needs it.

Comment: Ah, it's because when you are linking gcc, you are linking it to the current folder, not /usr/bin. Try ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc to link into /usr/bin so your OS finds it.

Answer (score 0):

When linking gcc, you are linking it to the current folder, not `/usr/bin`. Try

`ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc`

to link into /usr/bin so your OS finds it. You can also do `brew install gcc` if you use homebrew to get the latest version.

Comment: how can I do this inside a venv? I dont have the permission to do it

Comment: I tried brew install gcc, but I still get unable to execute gcc-4.2

Comment: You have to do ln with sudo

Comment: I still get "Operation not permitted"

Comment: Or am I supposed to deactivate my virtual env first?

Comment: The vietualenv has no bearing on your ln command. What command exactly did you type that you still get not permitted? What other warning text is there?

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc

gives me:
Password:
I enter my password
I get Operation not permitted

Comment: The operation is probably not permitted because you already have a copy of gcc on your computer. What happens when you just type `gcc` in your terminal? And the output of `which gcc`?

Comment: Typing gcc gives me clang: eror: no input files
Typing "which gcc" gives me: /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: So it means you have a thing called `gcc` in your PATH already. Try installing Cython again...